# Is there an event for when a raycast hits an object?

Tags: godot, raycasting, gdscript

Is there an event for when a Raycast collides with an object? I've been looking all over the internet for it, but there's just no results. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't. You only need to look at the official documentation on [`RayCast`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_raycast.html) (or [`RayCast2D`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_raycast2d.html) for that matter) to see that they don't define any signals.

What we do is check for [`is_colliding`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_raycast.html#class-raycast-method-is-colliding) on the physics frame (i.e. `_physics_process`).

If you prefer a signal, we can do it by attaching an script to it. Something like this:

```
extends RayCast


signal collided(collider)


var last_collider:Object


func _physics_process(_delta:float) -> void:
    if not is_colliding():
        last_collider = null
        return

    var found_collider:Object = get_collider()
    if found_collider != last_collider:
        last_collider = found_collider
        emit_signal("collided", found_collider)
```

You could even package it in an `EditorPuglin`, so it appears as an option when adding a `Node` in the editor. See [Making plugins](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/plugins/editor/making_plugins.html).

---

On the other hand, some people prefer to move away from the editor and do things from code. For that, you can always create the `RayCast` add it to the scene with `add_child`, and set its properties from code. *Remember to call `force_update_transform` and `force_raycast_update` as necesary.* Or even use [`intersect_ray`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_physicsdirectspacestate.html#class-physicsdirectspacestate-method-intersect-ray) (e.g. `get_world().direct_space_state.intersect_ray(start, end)`) which is a physics query that you can do at any moment, and does not require allocating a `Node`.

---

**Addendum**

> what if I want to call a function whenever the raycast STOPS colliding with an object?

We can use similar code to accommodate more signals. I'll overdo it for show. Remove what you don't want:

```
extends RayCast


signal entered(new_collider)
signal exited(old_collider)
signal collision_begin(new_collider)
signal collision_stop(old_collider)
signal collision_change(old_collider, new_collider)


var old_collider:Object


func _physics_process(_delta:float) -> void:
    var new_collider:Object = null
    if is_colliding():
        new_collider = get_collider()

    if new_collider == old_collider:
        return

    if old_collider == null:
        emit_signal("collision_begin", new_collider)
        emit_signal("entered", new_collider)
    elif new_collider == null:
        emit_signal("collision_stop", old_collider)
        emit_signal("exited", old_collider)
    else:
        emit_signal("collision_change", old_collider, new_collider)
        emit_signal("exited", old_collider)
        emit_signal("entered", new_collider)

    old_collider = new_collider
```

Here `"entered"` behave like `"collided"` from the prior example.

If you want a signal that happen when a particular object is no longer colliding, that is `"exited"`. If you want a signal when no object is colliding at all, that is `"collision_stop"`. *I couldn't tell which case are you interested in.*

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to call a function whenever the raycast STOPS colliding with an object?

Comment: @neksodebe See Addendum.